# Sylius/Symfony: Image Upload with custom entity

Tags: symfony, sylius

I'm trying to use Sylius' ImagesUploadListener for a custom entity.
In the [documentation](https://docs.sylius.com/en/latest/cookbook/images/images-on-entity.html) it says I should listen to an event like "sylius.shipping_method.pre_create". For my custom entity there is no event called that I could hook on.

So what I tried was hooking on the product.pre_create event and giving my entity as a parameter, but it seems that the image upload is only triggered on the product entity and my entity configuration is ignored. Although the ImagesUploadListener is triggered two times, once from the core and once from my configuration.

The error I get is "Column 'path' cannot be null" which basically means that the ImagesUploadListener was not performing the image upload before saving the entity.

```
    app.listener.images_upload:
        class: Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\EventListener\ImagesUploadListener
        parent: sylius.listener.images_upload
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: false
        public: false
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: sylius.product.pre_create, entity: MyBundle\Entity\MyEntity, method: uploadImages }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be an event to hook on if you created the entity correctly (the Sylius way). You need to define the entity as a Resource:

```
# config/packages/sylius_resource.yaml
sylius_resource:
    resources:
        app.name_of_etity:
            driver: doctrine/orm
            classes:
                model: App\Entity\NameOfEntity
```

If you defined the resource like this, the events would be:

```
event: app.system_manual.pre_create
event: app.app.name_of_entity.pre_update
```

Follow this guide:
https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.6/cookbook/entities/custom-model.html

**Update**

Because you are managing your custom entity through the existing product form the above will not work. To make it work, you can create your own event listener.

```
final class ProductSeoTranslationImagesUploadListener
{
    /** @var ImageUploaderInterface */
    private $uploader;

    public function __construct(ImageUploaderInterface $uploader)
    {
        $this->uploader = $uploader;
    }

    public function uploadImages(GenericEvent $event): void
    {
        $subject = $event->getSubject();
        // Add a ProductSeoInterface so you can use this check: 
        Assert::isInstanceOf($subject, ProductSeoInterface::class);
        foreach ($subject->getSeo()->getTranslations() as $translation) {
            Assert::isInstanceOf($translation, ImagesAwareInterface::class);
            $this->uploadSubjectImages($translation);
        }
    }

    private function uploadSubjectImages(ImagesAwareInterface $subject): void
    {
        $images = $subject->getImages();
        foreach ($images as $image) {
            if ($image->hasFile()) {
                $this->uploader->upload($image);
            }

            // Upload failed? Let's remove that image.
            if (null === $image->getPath()) {
                $images->removeElement($image);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tip: Create a (Product)SeoInterface so you can perform the type check.

Don't forget to register the eventListener:

```
App\EventListener\ProductSeoTranslationImagesUploadListener:
        tags:
            - {
                  name: kernel.event_listener,
                  event: sylius.product.pre_create,
                  method: uploadImages,
              }
            - {
                  name: kernel.event_listener,
                  event: sylius.product.pre_update,
                  method: uploadImages,
              }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am working on a sylius plugin, so I assume that the plugin namespace must be part of the event name. So far I tried: sylius.my_entity.pre_update,
my_bundle.my_entity.pre_update, sylius.my_bundle.my_entity.pre_update. But I always find the event name in the list of "Not Called Listeners". So these are not the events that are fired. Is there any way to find out which events were fired during the request?

Comment: Did you check the Orphaned Events tab in the Profiler? 
Did you defined your entity as a resource in your bundle? That ID should be the same as the event id.

Comment: There is nothing related in the Orphaned Events. The entity is defined as a resource with the name "sylius_better_seo_plugin.product_seo_translation". So I tried "sylius_better_seo_plugin.product_seo_translation.pre_update" as an event. I only see it in "Not Called Listeners".

Comment: I see you called it 'product_seo_translation' so i assume you are adding your entity fields to the existing Product form or is it a seperate form? If you are using the product form it should work with your original config 'sylius.product.pre_create'. So there might be some other problem

Comment: product > product_seo > product_seo_translation. Yes it is managed in the existing product form. But when I use the 'sylius.product.pre_create' then the image upload will be done for the product entity and not for the product_seo_translation entity.

Comment: I see, i actually had the same use case a while ago, see my updated answer.